# Salesforce SmartStore Android - Index Space on Relationship object

Tags: android, salesforce

I want to set index Spec for Custom relationship object in smart store when registering soup.

**Index Space**

```
private static IndexSpec[] POA_INDEX_SPEC =
    {new IndexSpec("Id", Type.string), new IndexSpec("Name", Type.string)};
```

How can i set custom relationship object ? I want to set **Machine__r.Name** in index spec.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can also add the custom relationship object into IndexSpec array.
Here is the solution.

```
private static IndexSpec[] POA_INDEX_SPEC =
    {new IndexSpec("Id", Type.string), new IndexSpec("Name", Type.string),new IndexSpec("Machine__r.Name", Type.string)};
```